# What is the big O notation of the following sentence

Tags: data-structures

What is the big O notation of the following function:

```
                             n^2 + n log n2^n
```

Comment: This doen't sound as `data-structure` but it really sounds as homework

Comment: The notation of your expression is ambiguous. Is that (log n) * (2^n) or (log n*2^n) or still something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use some [identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities) on the expression you provided:

<sup>2</sup> + log(2)

is:

<sup>2</sup> + [log + log(2)]

is:

<sup>2</sup> + [log + log2]

Now in terms of asymptotic complexity, O(log + log2) = O(), so then the big O for the whole expression is:

O(<sup>2</sup> + <sup>2</sup>) = O(<sup>2</sup>)